# cmake find_path/find_library failed check

Tags: find, cmake

I'm using [CMake 2.8.2](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_2.8.2_Docs) version. The project is using lots of external files and custom libraries (unavailable through find_package) and there is a long cascade of elements like the one below:

```
find_path(XXX_INCLUDE_DIR XXX.h /XXX/include)
if (XXX_INCLUDE_DIR)
  message(STATUS "Includes (XXX) found in ${XXX_INCLUDE_DIR}")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Includes (XXX) not found")
endif()
```

There is over 20 things like this in the script - it doesn't look good. According to the documentation, unfortunately, neither find_path nor find_library have a REQUIRED option which would do the job here (just like it does with find_package - if not found, the script stops). Do you have an idea how can I shorten the CMake script code? Something like

```
find_path(XXX_INCLUDE_DIR XXX.h /XXX/include REQUIED)
```

or something similar would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use either a [macro](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3amacro) or a [function](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afunction).

Answer (score 6):

Put them in your custom FindXXX.cmake modules. Read the [docs](http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Modules/readme.txt) and look at [`FindPNG.cmake`](http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Modules/FindPNG.cmake) for an example. Put them into `<project>/cmake/FindXXX.cmake` (or similar), and then add the directory containing these files to the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and use `find_package()`, e.g.

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(XXX REQUIRED)
```